# Interpreting and plot interactions between continuous variables in rma.mv ('metafor') outputs

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I was looking for ecologically-meaningful interactions in mixed-effects models of my meta-analysis when something nice (or at least I think!) came out.

My meta-analysis looks at plant diversity (i.e`Sratio`) loss or gain in natural ecosystems after fertilisation experiments around the globe. 
I wanted to see if mean annual temperature (i.e`MAT`) and the amount of nitrogen deposited from the atmosphere (a type of atmospheric pollution) (i.e`Ndep`) present across the sites analysed, exacerbate the effects of biodiversity change.

Thus, I fitted the following:

```
resi <- rma.mv(Sratio, Variance, mods = ~ Ndep*MAT, data = Sdat,random=~1|Experiment,
               method="ML")
```

Which gives you:

```
> resi

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 172; method: ML)

Variance Components: 

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed      factor
sigma^2    0.0498  0.2231    107     no  Experiment

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 168) = 201.7880, p-val = 0.0385

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3,4): 
QM(df = 3) = 13.8439, p-val = 0.0031

Model Results:

          estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt    -0.3799  0.0396  -9.6033  <.0001  -0.4575  -0.3024  ***
Ndep       -0.1717  0.0618  -2.7804  0.0054  -0.2928  -0.0507   **
MAT         0.1466  0.0435   3.3691  0.0008   0.0613   0.2319  ***
Ndep:MAT    0.0856  0.0356   2.4022  0.0163   0.0158   0.1555    *

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The interaction looks significant:

```
> anova(resi, btt=4)

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 4): 
QM(df = 1) = 5.7705, p-val = 0.0163
```

However, I have few problems to interpret what is going on in the output of `resi`.

**Questions:**

1) Is this the correct way to investigate what I want to test? or is the output of the same model without interaction (i.e `mods = ~ Ndep + MAT`) sufficient to test my hypothesis about temperature and nitrogen pollution?

2) Can you "visualise" `resi`? Can you plot this model to see what's appening?

Comment: Please read: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011#a_common_mistake_in_the_three-level_model You are only adding random effects at the `Experiment` level, when you should also add random effects at the estimate level.

Comment: Publications I found can report different experiments with different designs and even geographical locations. Therefore I clustered my observations into the `Experiment` variable to distinguish observations that comes from the same studies but are completely different. I can't understand why I should be interested to account for the publication itself in this case. I will try anyway your suggestion and thanks for your very nice package!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you should add random effects at the publication level (although that is something to consider _in addition_), but at the level of the estimates. In other words: `Sdat$ID <- 1:nrow(Sdat)` and then use `rma.mv(..., random = ~ 1 | Experiment/ID)`.

Comment: Thanks. However I always get the same result, ID seems not to have an influence when you look at Variance components in the output of the model: estim=0.0000 sqrt=0.0000

Comment: You might need to show the output from that model for @Wolfgang to comment further. Note it is best to ping him as I have just done.

Comment: @GabrieleMidolo That's fine then - so all of the variance is then at the `Experiment` level and none at the `Id` level. But it's good to have checked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you say I think the main effects are what you are interested in. If you fit a model with just them you can see the effect of temperature and the effect of nitrogen with each being controlled for the effect of the other. In the model you are currently fitting you have the interaction which tells you whether the effect of temperature is different depending on the amount of nitrogen. Either model could be interesting scientifically but I am not in your field so I cannot tell you which is interesting to you.

I am not sure what you mean by visualising the output but the standard plot is a forest plot backed up by a number of other plots like funnel plots.

Comment: Thanks mdewey. Indeed that would be very interesting in my field. My problem is how to read the estimate of the interaction terms (=0.0856) obtained from the model. Is it saying that the (negative) effect of hight temperature is stronger on Sratio when Ndep is higher?

Comment: I think the simplest thing is to do a 3d plot of predicted versus Ndep and MAT so you can see the shape of the surface.

Comment: two independent variables can not affect each other. but question says there is an interaction.